# how to view PDF from a list view which is fetch from Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity, pdfview

**I have fetched a PDF list view from Firebase Database**

This is the code that i used to fetch

```
public class ViewFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView myViewFiles;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
List<uploadFiles> uploadDOCS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_files);

    myViewFiles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myViewFiles);
    uploadDOCS = new ArrayList<uploadFiles>();

    viewAllFiles();

    myViewFiles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            uploadFiles uploadFiles = uploadDOCS.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadFiles.getUrl()));
            intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void viewAllFiles() {

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HNDIT").child("1st Year 2nd Sem").child("ENGLISH");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                uploadFiles uploadFiles = postSnapshot.getValue(com.example.lms.fileupload.uploadFiles.class);
                uploadDOCS.add(uploadFiles);
            }

            String[] uploads = new String[uploadDOCS.size()];

            for (int i=0; i < uploads.length; i++){
                uploads[i] = uploadDOCS.get(i).getName();

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads){
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    return view;
                }
            };
            myViewFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

**This is how it displays**
[Click here to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRS2l.png)

And i have create a intent for view these file in PDF view in android but it won't display keep blank this is the error it shows

E/PDFView: load pdf error
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])' on a null object reference
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:36)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

this is the code of that

```
public class ViewPdfFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

private PDFView pdfView;
private String url;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pdf_files);

    pdfView=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    }
    new RetrievePDFStream().execute(url);
}


class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void, InputStream> {
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try{

            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
                inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
    }
}
```

}

**This view parts xml code** [The Xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrnTO.png)

how can i fix this error and view files in android...

[image: Debug Part]
[image: When i click on a pdf from list view]
[image: How List view is displaying]

**This is how the files in my firebase database**
[the database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYE4Y.png)

Comment: I think your inputStream return null. Debug and check the data you are getting.

Comment: i have debugged and checked. it taking both file but parsing 1files url which is uploading to database last. i;m confused where should i want to correct.

Comment: Can you update you question with the response that you are getting from server?

Comment: edited with debug options

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me what you are getting in RetrievePDFStream post execute method. The data for the input stream.

Comment: sorry i have added the wrong images before now i have corrected it. when i click on the fetched pdf it want to display in my device without downloading.the 2nd code is which i developed for pdf view page. when i click on a pdf in list view it will move to that page.

Comment: whatever data you are loading to pdf view that is null please check that once. The Url is there or not.

Comment: how can i pass the url to my pdf page?? can u check my code and give me rply

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: which part that i want to see in the page there are several codes. which one that i want to select for get uri from the prvious page that i have fetched from databse

Comment: In between the code of my edited answer, try to log the value of `url` as 
`Log.d("url", uploadFiles.getUrl());` to see if the url is null or not there

Answer (score 0):

I want to start my answer with what you did wrong here :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadFiles.getUrl()));
        intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

You did all the important stuff in your `intent` object like setting it's `type` and `data` and then finally you ditched that **instance** for a **new `Intent`** instance. So now your `intent` object does know where to go i.e. `ViewPdfFiles.class` but does not have `data` or `type` set to it. Changing first line of code to
    `Intent intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);`
and removing **4th line** should work.
**Edited answer :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);;
//send data using putExtra(String, String) method if uploadFiles.getUrl() is string
intent.putExtra("url", uploadFiles.getUrl());
startActivity(intent);
```

**the null object**
[image: this is the error]

Comment: it's not getting anything simply white screen. what is the problem in it. i will edit your text with the image that what i see

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your `ViewPdfFiles.java`. To be able to retrieve `String` like that in your that activity, you need to send data using `putExtra()` method not using `setData()`. See my edited answer.

Comment: it didn't worked giving an null object i added it to ur code. 

(i'm getting files from my firebase database, i will added it to the same code)

Comment: see my newest edit. I did the same mistake in the last edit which I was suggesting you to not do in my unedited answer xD.

Comment: Still same bro is my ViewPdfFile.class codes are correct? i edit the error which is giving in RUN part

Comment: Sorry but from next time, edit your question stating about the new error and I will edit my answer to reflect the possible solution. You are updating my answer with your error and its so confusing xD