# How to open PDF viewer(adobe pdf) which in my mobile / emulator

Tags: java, android, firebase, pdf, viewer

When i click the file which i retrieve from database it will simply downloading. i want to open it from my PDF viewer which in my Mobile

I don't know how and where should i want to  change or replace the code

This is the List View

[A list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEEcT.png)

This is the code which i use to develop

```
public class ViewFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables
    ListView myViewFiles;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<String> detail;
    List<uploadFiles> uploadDOCS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_files);

        //Displaying the toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Assigning all the Variables to ID
        myViewFiles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myViewFiles);
        uploadDOCS = new ArrayList<uploadFiles>();

        detail =  new ArrayList<>();

        viewAllFiles();

        //On click option for the list view and open it from pdf
        myViewFiles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                uploadFiles uploadFiles = uploadDOCS.get(position);

                //Intent intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadFiles.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    //View files which in databse
    private void viewAllFiles() {

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HNDIT").child("1st Year 2nd Sem").child("OOP");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    uploadFiles uploadFiles = postSnapshot.getValue(com.example.lms.fileupload.uploadFiles.class);
                    uploadDOCS.add(uploadFiles);
                }

                String[] uploads = new String[uploadDOCS.size()];

                for (int i=0; i < uploads.length; i++){
                    uploads[i] = uploadDOCS.get(i).getName();

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads){
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        return view;
                    }
                };
                myViewFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

how can i fix this

Is there anyway to open inside the app

[Please see this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588920/how-to-view-pdf-from-a-list-view-which-is-fetch-from-firebase-database)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
Use this library. This is best way to load PDF into Application's screen.

Answer (score 0):

> When I click the file which I retrieve from database it will simply start
>   downloading.

`Intent.ACTION_VIEW` will try to **display** the pdf file. It requests the system to look for some `Activity` that is able to open and view this file. That's why it will start downloading. This should be **done only if you do not have special `Activity` in your own app that is capable of opening the file.**
Since, in this case, fortunately you do have your own capable `Activity` so, you should rather launch that `Activity` with `uri` of the pdf file as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewFiles.this, ViewPdfFiles.class);
//intent.setType(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("url", uploadFiles.getUrl());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it's not working

can u see this too i have upload the activity of pdfviewer 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588920/how-to-view-pdf-from-a-list-view-which-is-fetch-from-firebase-database/62185574#62185574